# SQL Server : cannot create index on view because it references derived table.

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I add a clustered index to the following view?

```
CREATE VIEW [vExcludedIds] 
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
    SELECT DISTINCT
        TempTable.Id 
    FROM
        (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS TempTable(Id)
```

And my index creation command is:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_V1   
ON [vExcludedIds] (Id);
```

And I get the following error:

> Cannot create index on view "Test.dbo.vExcludedIds" because it references derived table "TempTable" (defined by SELECT statement in FROM clause). Consider removing the reference to the derived table or not indexing the view.

Also, when I try to add the index manually in SQL Server Management Studio, I get an error at the top of "New Index" window saying:

> HasClusteredColumnStoreIndex: unknown property.

Any ideas please?

Comment: What is the purpose of this view?  Just create a table.

Comment: I have this issue too, but it works with sql command

Answer (score 8):

Please read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms191432.aspx

There are a lot of limitations for creating indexed views.

...
The SELECT statement in the view definition must not contain the following Transact-SQL elements:

- DISTINCT
- Derived table

Consider creating a table or table function

Comment: Link instructions result in error, example, table of users apply to position.  In table, is user_id and unique [id] for application.  SET ARITHABORT ON, create view SCHEMABOUND on unique index [id],[userid] columns  View comes back, immediately the error condition shows.   Even in a SQL 2014 database.   Did the parameters change?  Is underlying factor not described in the article defaulting database to always display error when trying to create a schemabound view with an index? Application is groovy with grails (much like entity framework) No idea why.